# Silverlight 5 failing to print large documents in Internet Explorer 9 but not Firefox

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-9, silverlight-5.0

In silverlight if i try to print a lot of controls in a Silverlight 5 application in IE9 then the print fails. Even if i try to print to XPS.

This always works in Firefox. When outputting the print to xps file in Firefox it is 221MB and i am aware of why these files are so large.

I have tried a number of things including printing to PDF and Running as administrator with no joy.

I have tried both `PrintDocument.Print()` as well as `PrintDocument.PrintBitmap()`

I know this is a common issue but can anyone offer any suggestions that I might not have tried before?

Thanks,

-- Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to sound a bit dense. But it looks like installing all the latest Windows Updates solved the problem.. Please try that if you have that issue.